# Put \item into a group so that typesetting effects are limited for the list entry

Tags: color, itemize, grouping

I want to have an implicit grouping for each `\item` in an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment to limit typesetting effects (coloring, emphasizing) to the respective `\item`.

E.g.,

```
\begin{itemize}
\item\color{red}
Cat
\item
Dog
\begin{itemize}
```

should behave like:

```
\begin{itemize}
{\item\color{red}
Cat}
\item
Dog
\begin{itemize}
```

which would enable me to provide specialized `\item`-types:

```
\begin{itemize}
\coloritem[red]
Cat
\item
Dog
\begin{itemize}
```

where `\coloritem` is an example for a specialized `\item`-type, which could be defined as follows:

```
\let\itemaux\item
\newcommand{\coloritem}[1][blue]{\color{#1}\itemaux}
```

The supplied code changes the color of "* Cat" to red, but is not limited to the `\coloritem`, so "* Dog" is also displayed in red instead of in the color that was active before the `\begin{itemize}`.

Comment: the deleted answer  basically solved it. You only need to store the current color and use that, e.g. `\AddToHook{env/itemize/begin}{\colorlet{mycurrentcolor}{.}}`

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike. Here is the complete code, which (1) redefines \item, and (2) checks for environments that are not concerned:
`\let\itemaux\item
\newcommand{\coloritem}[1][\defaultcolor]{\color{#1}\itemaux}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{\colorlet{itemcolor}{.}}}\@ifundefined{\string\color@itemcolor} {\itemaux}{\coloritem[itemcolor]}}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd redefine `\item` to have (just inside the `citemize` environment) a further optional argument in parentheses, to specify the color.

The trick is to save the current color at the beginning of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\NewDocumentEnvironment{citemize}{}{%
  \colorlet{current@color}{.}%
  \NewCommandCopy{\latexitem}{\item}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\item}{\citem}%
  \itemize
}{\enditemize}

\NewDocumentCommand{\citem}{d()o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\color{current@color}}{\color{#1}}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\latexitem}{\latexitem[#2]}%
}

\begin{document}

\color{gray!80}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{citemize}
\item(red) Cat
\item Dog
\end{citemize}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\bigskip

\color{black}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{citemize}
\item(red) Cat
\item Dog
\end{citemize}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

I'd *not* use `itemize` for this application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The version above does not work for nested lists, but when moving the \colorlet outside the environmentdefinition it does:
`\let\itemaux\item
\newcommand{\coloritem}[1][\defaultcolor]{\color{#1}\itemaux}
\let\itemizeaux=\itemize
\let\enditemizeaux=\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}
{\colorlet{itemcolor}{.}
\renewcommand{\item}{\coloritem[itemcolor]}
\itemizeaux}{\enditemizeaux}`